# Reduce the number of lines of code for recursive search

Tags: clojure

It's become an obsession of mine to reduce the lines of code that I write in Lisp/Clojure. I am trying to make the following code (essentially a depth first search) shorter.

```
(defn find-node  [nodeid in-node]
  (if (= nodeid (:id in-node))
    in-node
    (loop [node nil activities (:activities in-node)]
      (if (or (empty? activities) (not (nil? node)))
        node
        (recur (find-node nodeid (first activities)) (rest activities))))))

(defn find-node-in-graph [nodeid node activities]
  (if (empty? activities)
    node
    (recur nodeid (find-node nodeid (first activities)) (rest activities))))

(defrecord Graph [id name activities])
(defrecord Node [id name activities])
```

"activities" is a list

Comment: Would using tree-seq defeat the point of the question?

Comment: Some example input and output would help tailor the answers. I'm making up a tree format to use to provide an answer.

Comment: I was not sure if I'd just make the post too long and spammy. Yeah tree-seq was the macro that replaced those functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be cheating, though it's only one line ;)

```
(def tree {:id 1 :children [{:id 2 :children [{:id 3}]} {:id 4}]})

core> (filter #(= 3 (:id %)) (tree-seq :children :children tree)) 
({:id 3}) 

core> (filter #(= 2 (:id %)) (tree-seq :children :children tree))
({:children [{:id 3}], :id 2})
```

Some points on the original intent of the question:

- loop/recer is often not the most compact form, it wan usually be written with `map` or `doseq`
- if/recur can often be replaced with a call to `filter`
- If you seem to really need to write something like this because of some specific requirement, often [zippers](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html) will solve the problem more elegantly.

Comment: tree-seq was exactly what I needed. I knew that something as fundamental as a record would have something neat. You sir, have just participated in the galactic crusade for reducing the lines of code. Praise be to you.
In other words, tree-seq was exactly what I wanted.